# jQuery .animate working only on close

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate

I've used .animate() for a div in my design, and although it shows the content, it only shows the animation when closing, not when opening.

```
<div class="pull-right">
<a class="ix-lang" href="#">DE <img src="img/flag-de.png"/></a> 
<span class="ix-lang-more">
    <a href="#">EN <img src="img/flag-en.png"/></a> 
    <a href="#">ES <img src="img/flag-es.png"/></a>
</span>
</div>
```

The js:

```
$('.ix-lang').click(function(){
    $('.ix-lang-more').animate({width: 'toggle'});
})
```

And the CSS:

```
.ix-lang-more{
display:none;
width:60px;
height:14px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/tzyUz/

Any thoughts?

Comment: because you've used `display:none` in your css

Comment: can you use a value instead of toggle? let me know

Comment: Playing with the jsfiddle I just noticed exactly that. But if I use .hide() instead, the same problem happens.

Comment: hey you have to write a if else condition for show hide it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An inline element cannot have a width, and `<span>` is an inline element by default. When jQuery animates the opening, it increases the width and then displays the element, so it appears. When closing it, it sets the `display` to `inline-block`, which is the key here since the element must be inlined but still has to behave like a block because you want to resize it horizontally.

So [here it is](http://jsfiddle.net/Xk5Qn/).

Also don't forget `nowrap`; otherwise, the elements inside the `inline-block` `<span>` will wrap.

**Edit**: removed the CSS `width` property since `nowrap` makes this unnecessary (the inline block will stretch without wrapping so that everything it contains fits).

Comment: BTW, it's always better to use JavaScript to initially hide elements that are important like I did rather than using `display: none` since clients that don't support JS will still see them. This is called [Unobtrusive JavaScript](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unobtrusive_JavaScript).